# com.jaygoo.widget.RangeSeekBar : Android Seekbar show progress value along the seekbar

Tags: android, kotlin, price, rangeseekbar

I use as library "com.jaygoo.widget.RangeSeekBar" to get a Range Seek Bar.
Here's my following code XML :

```
 <com.jaygoo.widget.RangeSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rsb_min="1"
        app:rsb_max="5000"
        app:rsb_gravity="center"
        app:rsb_indicator_background_color="@color/white"
        app:rsb_indicator_show_mode="alwaysShow"
        app:rsb_indicator_text_color="@color/darkGrey"
        app:rsb_indicator_text_size="10sp"
        app:rsb_mode="range"
        app:rsb_progress_color="@color/honey"
        app:rsb_thumb_drawable="@drawable/circle"/>
```

This RangeSeekBar used to specify the price range, I would like to know How can I add the "$" symbol at the indicator in my seekrangeBar as the follwonig picture :
 [image]

I add the following kotlin code :

```
seekBarPrice.leftSeekBar.setIndicatorText("$1")
seekBarPrice.rightSeekBar.setIndicatorText("$1")
seekBarPrice.setRange(1F,5000F)
seekBarPrice.setOnRangeChangedListener(object: OnRangeChangedListener {
    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(view: RangeSeekBar?, isLeft: Boolean) {
    }

    override fun onRangeChanged(
            view: RangeSeekBar?,
            leftValue: Float,
            rightValue: Float,
            isFromUser: Boolean
    ) {
        Log.d("tag", "Value: $leftValue")
        seekBarPrice.leftSeekBar.setIndicatorText("$".plus(leftValue.toInt()))
        seekBarPrice.rightSeekBar.setIndicatorText("$".plus(rightValue.toInt()))
    }

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(view: RangeSeekBar?, isLeft: Boolean) {
    }
})
```

And my problem is solved

Comment: you could clone the library locally and modify as you need to

Comment: There's no other solution or other library to get what I want

Comment: i'm saying, clone the library you're already using from github, import it into your project and change it as you need to

Answer (score 1):

In your library to put % sign this way so you will change as per your requirement:

```
seekBarPrice.setIndicatorTextStringFormat("$%s%")
```

I hope it'll help you...!

Comment: I would like to thank you for your reply, but htis library give me one indicator and I want two indicator

Comment: What about this library "com.github.Innovattic:range-seek-bar:v1.0.6"

Comment: I still do not reach what I want

Comment: as per my answer you get % or not

Comment: Yes, I get % , But I don't want to get %
I just want to use RangeSeekBar  to specify the price range with two indicators and add "$" symbol to each one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204126/discussion-between-viral-patel-and-lina).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the right way

```
rangePrice.setOnRangeChangedListener(new OnRangeChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRangeChanged(RangeSeekBar view, float leftValue, float rightValue, boolean isFromUser) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(RangeSeekBar view, boolean isLeft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(RangeSeekBar view, boolean isLeft) {
            view.setIndicatorTextDecimalFormat("$%s%");
        }
    });
```